# Underscore indexOf() not working in AngularJS {{ }} interpolation

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

Say I've a simple array

```
$scope.array=[0,1,3,4,5,6];
```

and a view component where I want an ng-checked comparing with a vaule that must be in the array

```
`<ion-checkbox ng-checked="_.indexOf(array,1) !=-1"></ion-checkbox>`
`<ion-checkbox ng-checked="_.indexOf(array,2) !=-1"></ion-checkbox>`
```

I'm expecting the first checkbox  being checked and not the second but they are both checked.
Am I doing something wrong?
thanks for help

Comment: Is there a variable named `_` in your $scope? If not, `_` is undefined. Why do you (try to) use underscore to do that in the first place? JS arrays have an indexOf method.

Comment: Yes I'm using underscore _ everywhere in app controllers.. I will try straight JS though

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - AngularJS Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions).

Comment: Show us the code of your controller, where you define the _ variable of the $scope then.

Comment: As you're probably using `underscorejs` or `lodash`, when you're using it from the methods in your javascript files it works. But once you're using inside the `ng-checked` it's looking for something like: `$scope._.indexOf(...)`, if you want to keep using like this you can assign in your controller `$scope._ = _;`, but I prefer that you write a new method that receives your parameters and use the `_` inside it.

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS expressions are JavaScript-like code snippets that are mainly placed in interpolation bindings.

If you want to use Underscore, you should code a $scope function and call it:

Js:

```
$scope.exists = function(array, idx){
    return _.indexOf(array, idx) != -1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-checkbox ng-checked="exists(array,1)"></ion-checkbox>
```

Alternatively, you might write

```
$scope._ = _;
```

---

From a Dependency Injection point of view you should provide Underscore as a constant.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ion-checkbox ng-checked="array.indexOf(1)!=-1"></ion-checkbox>
```

You can try this one.

Comment: thanks to all, my question was over-simplified but you've cleared the concept.
regading the usage of `array.indexOf()` or even `_.indexOf()` when comparing with  the element with value `0` it always return false,. Said that I've worked around creating an object with string values, is there a safe way to match the  `0` value with indexOf() ?